# Timed jquery / back to top html css link

Tags: jquery, html, css, hyperlink, timed

I am trying to time my page to jump to different sections on my website. For example, if the user clicks a link saying contact us, it would jump lower down the page to the contact section (the page is a one page design with menu fixed to left). I want a 'timed' method so it scrolls rather than 'jump' appears. I found an example at http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/animated-scroll-to-top in jquery, does anybody know of a better tutorial for different parts of the site rather than just back to top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search the web for jquery Scroll to div and you will have results like [this](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/improved-animated-scrolling-script-for-same-page-links)

the [demo](http://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/#two)

you can  Recursively  call the function after a certain time (.delay()) with and dynamically change the div name.

Answer (score 0):

Link format : `<a href="#IDofElementToScrollTo">Click This</a>`

Target element : `<div id="IDofElementToScollTo"></div>`

```
$('a[href*=#]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this.hash);
    var elm = $(target).attr("id");
    var  loc = $(target).offset().top;
    $('body').animate({ scrollTop: loc}, 4000);
});
```

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Mft3T/

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out - I used some of yours and then below. Thanks!